# my flask api doesnt get my port even if i specify it

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, sh

my userapi

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        try:
            app_port = int(sys.argv[1])
        except ValueError as ve:
            app_port = 5558

        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=app_port)
    else:
        raise ValueError('No starting port for the application')
```

my startdocker.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
docker container stop userapi_cnt_ad
docker container rm userapi_cnt_ad
docker image rm userapi_img_ad
docker volume rm ad_vol
docker volume create --name ad_vol --opt device=/mnt/share/ad-infra-tp-2-h-2024 --opt o=bind --opt type=none
docker build -t userapi_img_ad -f ./project/docker/Dockerfile .
docker run -p 25556:5556 --mount source=ad_vol,target=/mnt/app --name userapi_cnt_ad userapi_img_ad
```

and my dockerfile

```
dont want to share my FROM file
COPY ./requirements.txt /
RUN pip3 install -r /requirements.txt
WORKDIR /mnt/app/
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/main/userapi.py"]
```

when i try ./startdocker.sh

it always gives me

```
File "./project/main/userapi.py", line 46, in <module>
raise ValueError('No starting port for the application')
ValueError: No starting port for the application
```

and i tried directly giving the app_port a port number, yes it works, but its not what i want because i am trying to test it later with another port

Comment: You need `CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/main/userapi.py", 5555]` where 5555 is the port

Comment: Right.  You are not passing a port number, so it's hardly surprising that your code didn't find one.

Comment: yeah, it works, but i have to put 5555 in "", is it normal

Comment: It makes sense that it would have to be in quotes.

Comment: why?, i am a student and trying to understand

Comment: By writing `dont want to share my FROM file` you made your question _non reproductible_. So try to understand by your own.   
Please, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two points you need to consider:

1. **sys.argv:** In python, `sys.argv` is the **list of command line arguments** passed to a python script. The first element `sys.argv[0]` is always the **script name**. So, if you are just running a command like `python userapi.py` (or in your case like `./run.sh ~/userapi.py`) you are not passing any argument and the length of the list would be always equal to one (`len(sys.argv) == 1`).
2. **CMD in docker:** specifies what command to run within the container. In other words, it specifies the instruction need to be executed when starting a container. This is where you can pass parameters and make sure the length of your system arguments is `sys.argv >=2`.
   There are two ways to use CMD command to run your instruction:

- **Method 1**: shell syntax

```
CMD executable parameter1 parameter2
```

- **Method 2**: use the JSON array format (recommended)

```
CMD ["executable", "parameter1", "parameter2"]
```

in your case:

```
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/main/userapi.py", "5556"]
```

**References:**

- Python docs [**sys.argv**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv)
- Docker [**CMD**](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-the-cmd-command-in-docker)

Answer (score 0):

You need in the `Dockerfile`:

```
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/main/userapi.py", "5555"]
```

where `5555` is the port you want to bind.

Your if statement test the numbers of arguments: as far as you don't pass any, you always throw the `ValueError`.

Comment: it worked but only if i but "" for the 5555. Is this normal

Comment: when i do that, it gives me the error that ./run.sh is not found

Comment: Yes, '5555'. Post edited accordingly. Looks like  a _type_ trick: `Int` (integer) VS `Str` (string).

Comment: If you're using `CMD` this way, it must be a JSON array consisting only of strings, and all of the individual words need to be wrapped in double quotes.  If it's wrong then Docker processes it as a shell command and you'll get an error like `[./run.sh: not found`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it make more sense to throw an error when an invalid port is provided, and use the default when none is provided?

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
        try:
            app_port = int(sys.argv[1])
        except:
            raise ValueError('Invalid port')

        if app_port < 0 or app_port > 65535:
            raise ValueError('Invalid port')
    else:
        app_port = 5558

    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=app_port)
```

Then, the following would use port 5558:

```
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/main/userapi.py"]
```

And you could override it as follows:

```
CMD ["./run.sh", "./project/main/userapi.py", "5555"]
```

Note the quotes since a JSON array of strings is expected.